# Money earned "in the UK" for family visa with regards to remote work

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, family, employment

I am in the process of bringing my long-term girlfriend to the UK as a partner.

We currently live together in her home country and according to the [financial requirement detailed guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/826340/Appendix-FM-1-7-Financial-Requirement-ext_1.pdf) section 5.2:

> the applicant’s partner must also have a confirmed offer of salaried or
>   nonsalaried employment in the UK

I'm curious about that final "in the UK" and how it relates to remote work. I'm considering making the switch to fully remote work upon return to the UK, which raises a few questions. I can't find an answer to these in the above guide.

Does "in the UK" mean:

1. Earned while I'm physically present in the UK (even if I were, for example, still working for my current company remotely)?
2. Earned working for a UK company (even if I stayed in my current country of residence)?
3. Paid into a UK bank account (even if I was working for a foreign company while living abroad)?
4. Any combination of the above?
5. Something else I haven't thought of?